# How to expand winform controls an equal amount as the form expands

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a row of buttons across a Winform, and as the form increases in size horizontally, i want the space between the buttons to increase the same amount but relative to their position on the form.  Rather than them being anchored left or right or middle, for it to be almost organic.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to do this?

Comment: Must you use Winforms? WPF is designed exactly for things like this, it will do this quite easily.

Comment: Anchor a TableLayoutPanel where each column is set to a percentage width.

Comment: So you want to increase the space between but not the buttons?

Comment: You may have to code the Resize/Resized event..

Answer (score 0):

I was always able to get acceptable results from using the anchoring, sometimes combined with frames.  Alternatives I looked at to get further control over behavior were frameworks both paid and free as well as using form events to capture when the form is resized and then using code to adjust control sizes.